# Customizing layout of community with Salesforce tab + Visualforce template

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites

I am using Salesforce tab + Visualforce template in my community.

Is there any way to customize the layout? I know how to customize the branding but it is not enough.

For example we do not want our customers to access "My Settings" page and the search bar, is there any way to remove them?

[image]

Also, what if I want to fully customize my community's UI? I found out [this link](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/u-Fck3VQxKNofTymNG-_zQ). Is it the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limits of official supported UI customizability. To remove 'My Settings' is clearly beyond. It also would break standard documented functionality and may end up in irritation and frustration of users.

So I think this requirement is a really bad idea.

The searchbar could be deactivated be disabling chatter for the customer profile. Typically you might want chatter for other profiles. Therefore you can log a ticket and ask them to enable a feature called "Profile-based chatter rollout"

Here is the branding docu  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_customize_branding.htm&language=en_US

All this might not apply to sites, where you have more design freedom and less functionality than in communities.

Comment: We are not trying to break the official UI indeed. We do not want to expose to much information to our customers such as OAuth record in "Approved Connections"
If there isn't any way to deal with this template I think we are going to fully customize our UI. 
http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/u-Fck3VQxKNofTymNG-_zQ
Is it the best approach for us to build a fully customize UI?

Comment: Haven't the time to watch the full video. If you create Visualforce pages for everything, you have full control over the layout but you will lose some standard functionality as a tradeoff.